# Encode input stream mpg2 to output stream h264 CBR

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, streaming, video-streaming

Output should be:
- 2,5 Mbit/s CBR H.264/mpeg4
- Audio 128kbit/s joint stereo mpeg2

Command i am using as last looks like this, and stream is not CBR.

```
ffmpeg.exe "udp://xxx.xx.xxx.x:xxxx?fifo_size=700000&buffer_size=12000k&pkt_size=1316" 
-vf "hqdn3d" -c:v libx264 -refs 4 
-minrate:v 2500k -me_method hex -maxrate 2500k -sc_threshold 45 -bufsize 300k -b:v 2500k-bsf 
h264_mp4toannexb -flags +ilme+ildct+loop+mv4+cgop -profile:v baseline 
-x264opts 8x8dct -x264opts mixed-refs -x264opts weightp=0 -g 100 
-c:a mp2 -ab 128k -ar 48000 -fflags +igndts+genpts+sortdts -f mpegts 
"udp://@xxx.xxx.x.x:xxxx?buffer_size=100k&pkt_size=1316" -threads 0 -v 0
```

Comment: @szatmary can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ffmpeg "udp://xxx.xx.xxx.x:xxxx?fifo_size=700000&buffer_size=12000k&pkt_size=1316" 
-vf "hqdn3d" -me_method hex -sc_threshold 45 -refs 4 -flags +ilme+ildct+loop+mv4+cgop -g 100
-c:v libx264 -minrate:v 2300k -maxrate 2372k -bufsize 2400k -b:v 2300k
-bsf h264_mp4toannexb -profile:v baseline 
-x264opts mixed-refs:weightp=0:nal-hrd=cbr  
-c:a mp2 -ab 128k -ar 48000 -fflags +igndts+genpts+sortdts
-threads 0 -v 0
-f mpegts -muxrate 2500k "udp://@xxx.xxx.x.x:xxxx?buffer_size=100k&pkt_size=1316"
```

Added `nal-hrd=cbr` to x264opts and removed `8x8dct` which is used in High profile.

If your input is interlaced, deinterlace it (add `yadif` filter).

Comment: The results are little better but not quite there. Not sure if input is interlaced, can you write example please on how to add yadif in your command so i can test it out ?

Comment: Use `-vf "yadif,hqdn3d"`. Are you looking at the total stream bitrate or only video?

Comment: Provider did not specify, but you might be right that its possible that total must be 2,5 mbit/s. So max and minrate in this case would be 2372k ?

Comment: I did, still variates a lot.

Comment: How did you decide to set the VBV buffer (300k)?

Comment: Have tried setting buffer to 100, 300, 2500, 5000, 7500. I read that it should be B divided by fps, but also that its trial and error. 300 was last one i tried with so thats why its there.

Comment: How much variation are you getting?